# IAR: Debugger Exits After Interrupt

Tags: embedded, iar

When I attempt to use breakpoints, rather than stopping at the breakpoint and allowing me to step through my program, IAR will exit to the default interrupt handler file for my STM chip. More specifically, it will stop and goes to the reset handler located in my startup file for IAR debugging.

I'm using an I-Jet which is their recommended debugging tool and this hasn't happened to me before on the same project. Is this a setting I overlooked or is this buggy behavior someone else has found as well? Usually when I hit pause or put in a breakpoint it stops at that point in the file so I can watch my variables as I run through the program. IAR 8.40.2 if that helps.

Comment: Do you have a watchdog timer enabled, that is not configured to pause when you hit a breakpoint? That would produce symptoms like this.

Comment: Set another breakpoint at the interrupt handler to stop further execution. Then look at the return address in the stack to see where you come from.

Comment: Are you debugging optimized code?  Usually best avoided.

Answer (score 1):

@pmacfarlane was correct. I had enabled a watchdog that would prompt IAR to go to the system reset file rather than pausing on a breakpoint. Code is actually set as optimized but that has not seemed to affect these symptoms.